# Passing a value to Html.Editor extension method

Tags: c#, html, razor

I am writing a custom `HtmlHelper` extension method, and at one point I want to fall through to the standard `EditorExtensions` method `Html.Editor`. The only catch is that I also want the resulting element to have a particular value (which I resolve from the code at runtime).

I have tried passing in my value as an HTML attribute in the `additionalViewData` argument:

```
// Simplified method for illustrative purposes
public static MvcHtmlString MyCustomEditor(this HtmlHelper html, string expression, string externallyResolvedValue)
{
    var additionalViewData = new { htmlAttributes = new { value = externallyResolvedValue } };
    return html.Editor(expression, additionalViewData);
}
```

Unfortunately this fails, and I presume (without starting to decompile assemblies) that this is because the value set by the `Editor` method is bound to the `value` attribute after the `additionalViewData` gets processed (I can, for instance, set other HTML attributes using this mechanism, it's just `value` that fails).

Obviously, I know that I could set the value of the element using JQuery, but the problem with this is that I cannot easily communicate `externallyResolvedValue` to the Javascript from the point in the code at which it is known. Moreover there are going to be quite a few calls to `MyCustomEditor`, so the far tidier mechanism would definitely be to do it in code, if this is possible.

Any bright ideas?

**EDIT:**

One other possible solution which has just occurred is to do a Regex on the resulting `MvcHtmlString` and replace the `value` by hand, but this seems rather more like a hack than a fix... It seems like there should be a much more elegant solution to this.

Comment: You can manipulate `ModelState` for that particular property, from within the extension method or if you have access to model itself, just update the property value.

Comment: Currently `Html.Editor` doesn't actually resolve a value. The `expression` variable is a deep property path with indexes, so the engine isn't smart enough to work out what the value ought to be based on the backing model I have at the time. I am in fact just trying to set the value from the backing model!

Comment: (or at least the value being resolved is an empty string, and is overwriting the actual value which I'm trying to set c.f. my second paragraph)

Comment: Editor extension methods resolve it from ModelState if present, else from property value. So update either of them before calling the method.

Comment: Perhaps I am not using the correct syntax for the `expression` argument then? I'm dealing with properties of the form: `Prop1.Prop2[someIndex1].Prop3[someIndex2]...` etc. I believe the indexers are what is causing my grief, but either way I'm getting an empty string as the resolved value. Also unfortunately I cannot use the generic `EditorFor` accepting a lambda, I realise that this would solve my problem

Comment: And to clarify - that is the form in which I am constructing my `expression` string

Comment: If you don't do any manipulation on html attributes, does it resolve correctly?

Comment: No. I only started manipulating html attributes in order to mitigate this, in an ideal world I would love to just do nothing and let `Editor` do all the hard work for me! However as I say I'm getting an empty value back, and my backing `ModelState` is definitely non-empty for that property path. I can find very little documentation about the syntax for `expression` though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at — and imitating — the MVC source code may be easier than you think, and easier than working around it.

Look at these examples:
[GitHub Asp.Net MVC repo: DefaultEditorTemplates.cs](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/0ee98f84b41b6bef6bde6945e2797de9dac7d48a/src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/DefaultEditorTemplates.cs)

```
private static string HtmlInputTemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, string inputType, object value)
{
    return html.TextBox(
            name: String.Empty,
            value: value,
            htmlAttributes: CreateHtmlAttributes(html, className: "text-box single-line", inputType: inputType))
        .ToHtmlString();
}
```

[GitHub Asp.Net MVC repo: InputExtensions.cs](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/0ee98f84b41b6bef6bde6945e2797de9dac7d48a/src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs)

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBox(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name)
{
    return TextBox(htmlHelper, name, value: null);
}

public static MvcHtmlString TextBox(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, object value)
{
    return TextBox(htmlHelper, name, value, format: null);
}

public static MvcHtmlString TextBox(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, object value, string format)
{
    return TextBox(htmlHelper, name, value, format, htmlAttributes: (object)null);
}
```

and you can see that there are overloads which take a value parameter. Can you replace `Html.Editor()` in your code with `Html.TextBox()` ?

Comment: Thanks @Chris this may indeed prove to be my best option. Truth be told, I was less concerned about the generality lost by replacing `Editor` with `TextBox` than I am about the model binding when I post back, but I hadn't actually spotted that `TextBox` renders the same `id` attributes as `Editor` so this is actually more feasible than I'd thought. It's certainly nicer than doing a Regex... trying it out now!

Comment: Actually that's working a dream, thanks! When I get around to it I will probably do a type check and work out whether to do a `TextBox` or `CheckBox` or whatever (and probably wrap that all up in another nice little extension method) but in the meantime I think this is just going to work for 90% of my cases anyway, so pretty happy!